# getRowId from Material UI datagrid doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I keep getting this error **Uncaught Error: MUI: The data grid component requires all rows to have a unique `id` property.** Even though I have passed the getRowId prop into the datagrid and defined what the Id should be. I am fetching this data from a firestore. What might I be doing wrong? Here is the component code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../../firebase/firebase";

import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";

const columns = [
  { field: "name", headerName: "Name", width: 160 },
  { field: "email", headerName: "Email", width: 210 },
  { field: "roles", headerName: "Roles", width: 160 },
  { field: "isSuspended", headerName: "Suspended", width: 130 },
  { field: "lastUpdated", headerName: "Last Updated", width: 150 },
  { field: "updatedByEmail", headerName: "Updated By", width: 150 },
];

export default function Admins() {
  const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getAdmins = async () => {
      const admins = await getDocs(collection(db, "admins"));
      admins.forEach((admin) => {
        setRows((row) => [
          ...row,
          {
            id: admin.data().email,
            name: admin.data().name,
            email: admin.data().email,
            roles: admin.data().roles,
            isSuspended: admin.data().isSuspended,
            lastUpdated: admin.data().lastUpdated,
            updatedByEmail: admin.data().updatedByEmail,
          },
        ]);
      });
    };

    getAdmins();
  }, []);

  console.log("rows", rows);

  return (
    <div style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100%" }}>
      <DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        getRowId={(row) => row.email}
        pageSize={10}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[10]}
        checkboxSelection
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion is to first check if you are getting the value for the `row.email` in case is returned as undefined and try using optional chaining `getRowId={(row) => row?.email}`

Comment: I did the optional chaining and that didn't work as well.

Comment: Can you try to replace with getRowId={(row) => row.no} or with getRowId={() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000)} and make sure that each email is unique in case there are duplicated emails? Thanks